# Is this a comparative correlative and does it need a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, comparative-constructions

It seems that most conventional examples of *comparative correlative*, e.g.

> The further you go, the harder it gets.

can be transformed in the following way:

> It gets (the) harder[,] the further you go.

Another example (a simplification of what I need for my text):

> The smaller the size of the object, the greater its index.

→

> The index of the object is the greater[,] the smaller that object's size is.

My questions are:

1. Are the second versions still comparative correlatives?
2. Either way, are the commas in brackets needed there?

Comment: Perhaps your "transformations" might help you to *understand* the comparative correlative construction, but they're not idiomatic. So it's not really relevant to ask whether the commas would be required or not (but "in principle", they would be required, because they *would* reflect necessary pauses in speech).

Comment: @FumbleFingers the thing is, it is this "transformed" construction that I want to use because I believe it fits my text situation better, whether or not such use is idiomatic. I could instead just supply my actual sentence, but I think this wouldn't be as generally useful and hence not in the spirit of a Q&A forum.
I didn't understand your point on "relevance", though. I can see how labelling a non-idiomatic use may be irrelevant, but commas?

Comment: @FumbleFingers what's non-idiomatic about "it gets harder the further you go"?

Comment: Yes: your suggested alternants are correlatives that have the subordinate clause in end position, whereas your originals have it in front position, which is very much the more common version. Generally, a comma is used in the latter kind, but not the former.

Comment: I meant it's not idiomatic to include the ("to be paralleled") article ***the*** in your transformations. Which by extension means that those transformations themselves are somewhat less "parallel" when rephrased (so they're not really such good examples of the comparative correlative construction under consideration).

Comment: @BillJ thank you! Would you mind adding what you wrote there as an answer? Also, by the "latter kind" you meant the "originals", right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers ah, so the definite articles in the former parts are unnecessary, like in how Maciej Stachowski wrote it, with "harder" instead of "the harder"?

Comment: Yes. If you change the sequence so the comparative comes *after* the verb (as in *It **gets harder** as you **go further***), you don't want the article. I'd say the article is effectively a component of the "fixed form" construction, which by it's very nature includes ***two*** structurally identical clauses. It's possible to retain the original structure in just ***one*** half (as you did), or discard it from ***both*** halves (as I did in this comment). But unless it's the "fixed form - comparative before subject+verb", the article isn't appropriate.

Comment: The article **is** possible in the non-fronted comparative phrase, but rare. This is acceptable: "The index of the object is [**the** greater] [the smaller] that object's size is"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1a] [*The further*] *you go,* [*the harder*] *it gets.*

[1b] *It gets* [*harder*] [*the further*] *you go.*

[2a] [*The smaller*] *the size of the object,* [*the greater*] *its index.*

[2b] *The index of the object is* [*greater*] [*the smaller*] *that object's size is*.

The paired correlative phrases are bracketed.

Yes: your suggested alternants (the b. examples) are correlatives. They have the subordinate clause in end position, whereas your originals (the a. examples) have it in front position, which is very much the more common version.

Generally, a comma is used in the a type, but not the b type.